# Auto close $form.ShowDialog() on selection of default selected text

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a custom form and I need to auto close the window on selection of selected part of the text displayed on the that form window

`Show-OAuthWindow` shows the dialogue box for user consent and I want to avoid using `showdialog()` and select the auto-selected text on the window

```
Function Show-OAuthWindow {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=600;Height=800}
    $web  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{Width=580;Height=780;Url=($url -f ($Scope -join "%20")) }
    $DocComp  = {
            $Global:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri
            if ($Global:Uri -match "error=[^&]*|code=[^&]*") {$form.Close() }
    }
    $web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
    $web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
    $form.Controls.Add($web)
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: "*close the window on selection of selected part of the text*"? Could you rephrase the question and make it a bit clearer? What's the requirement? What's the problem in the code which you tried for solution?

Comment: A working example with data would help - all that script does is issue a blank form.

Comment: I am basically doing a oauth authentication &authorization through mandatory user consent to generate the token to connect to sharepoint online through azure

Comment: what I have explored till now that I need to get the user consent using custom form which I explained earlier,my code is working but I want to run it through Azuredevops pipeline and in that I can't use any pop-up window to take user consent,the above code does produce the Microsoft consent form